# make custom calculation in prestashop for one product

Tags: php, prestashop

I would like to know in which file in presta shop the product price is calculated? I have added two attributes to one of the products, but I would like to do something like

```
 if(product_id = 44) {
    attribute1 + (attribute1 x attribute2) = the price
  }else {
    the usual calculation...
  }
```

Right now the price changes according to what is selected in attribute1 + attribute2, I couldnt find any help on presta documentation and I really need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering that your are using Prestashop 1.5.x .

In Classes/Product.php , there is a function which codes is below:

```
public static function getProductAttributePrice($id_product_attribute)
{
    return Combination::getPrice($id_product_attribute);
}
```

or you can work directly in the

```
Combination::getPrice($id_product_attribute);
```

What you will need to do it to override the combination class or the product class, and overload that function. Lets take Combination class, because the getProductAttributePrice will be deprecated in future.

So override the Combination class and overload the getPrice function. What you will need to do is to pass the product id also to it so that you can make your calculations.

Now you may know your attributes ids for this, so if product id is 144, then then both attributes prices, and process them accordingly and return it.

**Note: It is just to give you an idea. It may or may not work.**

I hope it will help. If still you did not get your results, then let me know, and i will reply.

Thanks